# Unable to find a way to resize an image using PHP

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I want to resize any image uploaded to 200*200 pixels.I have been looking over scripts all over the net,have found many but unable to use any.I don't want any other controls just resizing it to specific size.

```
<!-<?php session_start();?>
<?php session_start();?>
<?php $u_name=birju;?>
<?php require_once("mydb.php");?>
<?php

         define ("MAX_SIZE","100"); 


         function getExtension($str) {
                 $i = strrpos($str,".");
                 if (!$i) { return ""; }
                 $l = strlen($str) - $i;
                 $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
                 return $ext;
         }


         $errors=0;

          if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
         {
            $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
            if ($image) 
            {
                $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
                $extension = getExtension($filename);
                $extension = strtolower($extension);
         if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
                {
                    echo '<h1>Unknown extension!</h1>';
                    $errors=1;
                }
                else
                {
         $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

        if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
        {
            echo '<h1>You have exceeded the size limit!</h1>';
            $errors=1;
        }

        $image_name = $u_name.'.'.$extension;
        $newname="images/".$image_name;
        $copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
        if (!$copied) 
        {
            echo '<h1>Copy unsuccessfull!</h1>';
            $errors=1;
        }}}}

         $me=mysql_query("insert into img_upload values(\"\",\"$u_name\",\"$newname\")");
         if(!$me)
         {
             die("database query failed".mysql_error());
         }

?>

         <!--next comes the form, you must set the enctype to "multipart/frm-data" and use an input type "file" -->
         <form name="newad" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="">
         <table>
            <tr><td><input type="file" name="image"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Upload image"></td></tr>
         </table>   
         </form>
-->
```

Comment: If you are going to down vote, please add a comment as to why.

Comment: I got various javascripts from net to resize...they provided various controls...however i just wanted to resize it to specific size before it gets stored in local server folder...can't there be just few more lines added to this code so image could be resized specifically

Comment: http://php.net/imagecopyresampled    you haven't looked "all over" far (or deep) enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PHP GD, instead of your code about copying the image from tmp_name to new_name use:

```
$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);
imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 200, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
file_put_contents($newname, $new_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out timthumb: http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/